# Are requests to help "fix up" a resume/CV permitted?

Tags: discussion

[How can we draft better profile for CV?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/47276/how-can-we-draft-better-profile-for-cv)

Is this sort of question permissible?

Answer (score 6):

Workplace SE is not a resumé review site; therefore, this question is off topic. It is also too broad for Stack Exchange.

However, the [list of topics for Workplace SE](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) does say that questions about resumés and CV's are on topic, but the questions would have to be well scoped and more specific than an overall review.

I put the post on hold and left a comment on the question-asker's post with suggestions to focus on something more specific.  I also suggested using our chat, as folks may be able to better help in a real time format, considering the language barriers.

Answer (score 5):

If the question is to ask for a rewrite of the resume it has to be off topic.

Why?

- It would only be applicable to one person;
- it would be impossible to know which answer was better.
- we don't have enough information about their job history to be able to do more than grammar and punctuation changes, unless we asked them a lot more questions.