# Resume Related Questions

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition

Until recently I was under the impression that we did not deal with resume related questions.  The fact that we apparently do in some cases is perfectly fine by me.

Resumes however do introduce a considerable amount of opinion in terms of what makes a good one or bad one, what to include or not include, etc.

How do we handle the *line* as to what we **will or will not take on** as it relates to resume related questions?

Comment: I'd say this is actually pretty succintly answered by the off-topic close reason [here](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2596/25739). Additional questions of interest for the side-bar: [1](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3185/25739), [2](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/can-we-ask-for-resume-review-here-in-the-workplace), [3](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3741/25739).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We do not do review, design, or write my resume questions.

We do answer general questions on how to build, structure, and format a resume or CV abstractly and even some limited focused cases.

Comment: Yes, I think the key word is **review**. If a post asks for us to review a resume then that would be off-topic. Otherwise, chances are it is on-topic

Comment: Excellent clarity provided sir!

Comment: How to structure and phrase general things on a resume, is fine, to some extent. I'm not so sure about how to build (?) or format a resume though (which I imagine would be things like "which font should I use", but maybe you had other questions in mind here) - such questions seem highly opinion-based.

Comment: @Dukeling - I clarified further

Answer (score 2):

I find that focus on opinion a bit weird. A lot of stuff here focuses on opinion because we are talking about humans. This is not [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/).

I think checking entire resumes goes a bit beyond the mission here but questions about resumes should be possible.